# How do I download the all_user.csv report from GitHub Enterprise with vb.net and avoid a 404 error? I can can do this using Curl

Tags: vb.net, curl, github-enterprise

I am attempting to download GitHub Enterprise's all_users.csv file via vb.net using .net framework 4.5.2 and get the following error: 
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

My code is:

```
Module Module1 
 Sub Main() 
  Dim remoteUri As String = "https://ghe.webserver/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv" 
  Dim fileName As String = "all_users.csv" 
  Dim password As String = "PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" 
  Dim username As String = "USERNAME"

  System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True 
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

  Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient 
  client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password) 
  client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName) 
 End Sub

End Module
```

The error occurs at the line `client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName)` with the full exception

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Module1.vb:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The following Curl command however works (as described here:https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/admin/installation/site-admin-dashboard#reports): 
`curl -L -u USERNAME:PERSONALACCESSTOKEN --insecure https://ghe.webserver/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I've added the full exception to my question @RobertBaron